# Confused about the $\pm$ sign?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, arithmetic

I have multiple questions about the $\pm$ sign, since it seems to confuse me in general...

**Question 1:**

Say I have $15=\pm(a+x)$, Can I use the distributive property so it becomes $15=\pm a \pm x$? Or does that mean I went from 2 to 4 solutions?

I get very confused when I encounter this sign in equations I need to simplify. Whenever I need to deal with these kind of situations I tend to just turn it into two equations, $15= a+x$ and $15=-a-x$. But if I were to do that with bigger equations that still need to be simplified it means I'm wasting alot of time since I'm doing twice the labor...

**Question 2:**

Does the $\pm$ sign only make sense in equations, or can they be used in normal expressions as well (e.g. $\pm y + 3$). But then I wonder, in what scenario would you do something like this?

**Question 3:**

$\sqrt {x^2}+37=y+40$

Say I were to simplify $\sqrt{x^2}$ in that equation, I don't know where I should put the $\pm$ sign. Where would I put it? The extra terms 37 and 40 confuse me...

Comment: Your strategy of turning it into two equations is a very sensible one, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the $\pm$ sign is confusing you, get rid of it.  If you have $$15 = \pm(a+x)$$ you can turn that into two equations:  $$15 = a+x\\15 = -(a+x)$$ and then deal with the two equations separately, one at a time.  That is exactly the meaning of the $\pm$ sign.

---

The reason you're confused is because the notation is confusing!  The expression $\pm a \pm b$ is actually ambiguous: in some contexts it means four values, and in other contexts it means two. Sometimes there is a convention that the two $\pm$ signs must represent the same sign; sometimes there isn't.

In your third example, I'd suggest that you write $z = \sqrt{x^2}$ and turn the equation into $z+37 = y + 40$.  Then solve as usual.  When you get to the end, you have $z$ and $y$.  Then you can conclude that $x$ could be either $z$ or $-z$.

Comment: I like that solution for the third example. Would you think substituting it with z would be better than just changing it to |x|? I'd like to be consistent in which method I use.

Comment: Do whichever you find easiest to think about.

Answer (score 2):

**1:** Yes, you can distribute it.
Well, it works for all cases.
$$\pm(x + y) = \pm x \pm y \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$$

The basic properties are:
$$(-)\times (\pm) = (\mp)\\
 (\pm)\times(\pm) = (+)\\
 (\mp)\times(\mp) = (+)\\
 (\pm)\times(\mp) = (-)
$$

---

**2:**
As you said, $\pm$ is used to represent $+$ and $-$ in separate equations. It's a bit more fundamental than that. Even as a statement

$$x \pm y  \implies x+ y \text{ and } x - y$$

There isn't a real usefulness for it rather than saves time in writing and speaking.
For example,

> I ask you, " What is $\sin(A\pm B)$ ?" 
>    You'll tell me, " $\sin A \cos B \pm \cos A \sin B$"

I've recently been using it to  help my little brother practice both addition and subtraction simultaneously,

$$3 \pm 2 \to 5, 1\\
32 \pm 23 \to 55, 9\\
1729 \pm 999 \to  2728 , 1630\\
854297992 \pm 299792458 \to 1154090450, 554505534\\
\dots$$
He's been getting really good at it.

---

**3**: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

Take the points $\pm x$ on a number line (Hopefully, you understand the usage now)
The distance to those points from the origin can be found by the distance formula:
$$\sqrt{(\pm x - 0)^2} = \sqrt{x^2}$$

Now, $\sqrt{x^2} = x ,\quad\forall x\in [0, \infty)$
and $\sqrt{x^2} = -x ,\quad\forall x \in (-\infty, 0)$

So, it always outputs the magnitude of $x$

Let's try playing with that equation you've given using our knowledge of this:
$$\sqrt {x^2}+37= y + 40 \\
\implies |x| = y + 3 \\
\implies x = y + 3, \space\forall y\in [-3, \infty)\quad\text{ and }\quad x = - (y+3), \space\forall y\in (-\infty, - 3)$$

Comment: @TonyK Not necessarily, in some contexts $\,\pm a\pm b\,$ means $\,ua + ub,\,$ where $\, u = \pm1 .\ $

Comment: So should I turn it into an absolute value in my equation? e.g. |x| + 37 = y + 40?

Comment: @Nick: the OP might need some explanation. 'Yes' isn't really a hint, I think.

Comment: Yes. (To convince yourself why this is, plug in a few values. For example: $\displaystyle\sqrt{(3)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3=|3|$, $\displaystyle\sqrt{(0)^2}=\sqrt{0}=0=|0|$, $\displaystyle\sqrt{(-3)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3=|-3|$. (Remember that the $\sqrt{\;}$ sign means "the positive root").

Comment: @barto: Done! Explanation added.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: This is something the OP has to convince himself. There are just too many funda-level questions about |x| on this site. But yes, I've added a bitmore explanation!

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(-x) = y+3$ instead of $x = - (y+3)$? (You've just explained that $|x|$ is either $x$ or $-x$ depending on the sign. So, to make it less confusing, you should have just plugged in $x$ and $-x$ into the equation.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Unless, he's in the 5th grade, I don't think I need to explain why $$-x = a \iff x= -a$$
In due time, I'll keep expanding what I said.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{Question\ 1:}$ The plus or minus sign does not distribute like that. To see this, consider the equation $x^{2}-4=0$. It should be obvious that the roots of this equation are $\pm 2$. We can rewrite that as $\pm (10-8)$ since $10-8=2$. However, Distributing the $\pm$ sign through $(10-8)$ would imply that $18$ and $-18$ are also roots of $x^{2}-4=0$.

$\bf{Question\ 2:}$ It can be used as you have specified, although it is not very common to see that.

$\bf{Question\ 3:}$ The quantity $\sqrt{x^{2}}$ is used to denote the magnitude of $x$, which is $|x|$.

Comment: For question 1: Not necessarily. More often than not, if there are two $\pm$ signs in an equation, they have to either be both plus or both minus. (If there is a $\mp$ in the equation, it usually means the opposite sign from whatever the $\pm$'s are.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw You are right about Question 3, but you are saying exactly what I was trying to say in question 1. ie. There are not four solutions to $\pm(10-8)$, there are only two. It is a good point that more than one set of $pm$ signs can appear in an equation. The signs do need to match when this happens.

Comment: You're trying to argue that $\pm10\mp8$ implies four solutions, while I'm trying to argue that it can imply two - unless I'm mistaken about what you're trying to say.

Comment: I was showing why it has to be wrong if you get four solutions, namely because it would mean $18$ and $-18$ are roots to $x^{2}-4=0$

Comment: OP was asking if the _notation_ implied four solutions. (The question isn't - _is it wrong if I get four solutions?_ but _does writing it this way falsely imply that there are four solutions?_)

Comment: Yes... In my first sentence I say "no, the $\pm$ sign does not distribute like that [in a way that gives four solutions]". I was providing OP an example to show why the $\pm$ sign does not distribute as they initially thought it might.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I misinterpreted that first sentence.

Answer (score -1):

what if variable x = +1 and y = -1, since it is a variable, maybe 4x could be 4+1= 5, not multiplication in this state? y= -1, 2y = 2-1 = 1.
4x -2y=3.
4x-2y=3
_____=3
           _

4-2y=4-2y
x = 3
    ______
     4-2y

3             = +1

---

4-2y

3
-   = +1
3

x=+1 , y=-1

Comment: This could be considered more of a comment . Until you have earned enough reputation to comment please try to leave only clear and concise answers with good explanation and please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format answers. welcome to the SE community.